# What is the best Menu pattern for large dataset?

Tags: design-patterns, menu

I was searching on various UI components that is out there.
new, old and more.

I want to know, Are there any good website which lists and compares
web UI components?

I am specifically looking for Menu patterns.

e.g. For Menu, on top of my mind and initial research (from http://ui-patterns.com/patterns) gives some common examples like,
1. Vertical Dropdown Menu
2. Horizontal Dropdown Menu
3. Accordion Menu

EDIT 1:
The above question seems to be bit broad. To narrow down my question.
What is the best Menu pattern that can be used, if I have 20 main categories and say 50 sub-categories inside each one of them. e.g.

MainCategory1
 SubCat1
 SubCat2
 .
 .
 .
 SubCat50
MainCategory2
MainCategory3

If I choose normal accordion then 50 subcategories overflow the window and usually needs to scroll a lot. What is the best way of dealing data like the above.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the large number of subcategories? Could they maybe be categorized in a different manner?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using columns within a single menu, similar to how Netflix and many other sites do it:

[image: Netflix.com]

With this many items, you'll want to consider two additional factors A) Sorting options and B) Flags that could highlight items of interest to users (trending? personalized ranking? number of sub-items?).

Comment: I like this idea. Amazon's big nav is similar in some ways, so maybe look at that as well? http://i.imgur.com/jV1ZLv0.png